# ROS Answers SE migration: USB 3.0 Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, usb, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone !

I have a question..

I want to do this tutorial "http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data"

but.. when i enter this command "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch", i cannot connect to kinect..

My usb-port is 3.0.. I think it is matter..

how can i connect ? or change ? this problem?  t.t

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30474/usb-3.0-kinect/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it does matter. The Kinect unfortunately does not work with USB 3.0. If your computer has a USB 2.0, you should use that instead.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-26**:
More on this topic here: http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30